# How do I install OBS?

Tags: software-installation, desktop-recording, obs-studio

I need a screen recorder and OBS is the best. How can I install the latest version on Ubuntu?

Comment: A useful question: Google offered me no less than eight how-to-install tutorials, most of which were long obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

[`obs-studio` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=obs-studio&searchon=names) is available in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 19.04 and 19.10 (pre-beta).

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install obs-studio`.

Comment: it says: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
"

Comment: @Adam are you sure `dpkg` is not running? Try to kill the process of dpkg by running `sudo killall -SIGTERM dpkg`. If you still can't, might as well as removing file inside `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`. (only do it for last resort!)

Comment: Permition denied

Comment: Just FYI, note that this does not seem to work for Ubuntu 16.04. You need to use the ppa for that.

Answer (score 6):

Referring to the [official GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#linux), you can also use [`ppa` provided by them](https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio) to install it for 15.04 and above (if there is no package in the repository).

Run this commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install obs-studio
```